# C# setting object as null

Tags: c#

I want to set an object as null so I can 'consume' it of sorts.
In Java we have this.

```
//In some function/object
Vector3 position = new Vector3();

//In some loop.
if(position != null){
    consumePositionAsForce(position);
    position = null;
}
```

I'm aware in C# that one has to 'Box' the and 'Unbox' the object if you are using primitive types buut I cannot find any documentation on nullable value types.

I'm trying to do the same in C# but I'm getting an errors/warning about type cast. As in I cannot set Vector3 = null.

Comment: What error or warning? Share the C# code as well

Comment: Maybe you want `Vector3?`?

Comment: Vector3 is a struct, you need to convert it to a `System.Nullable<Vector3>`

Comment: Reference types have null as a default value so you just assign null.  There's a *lot* of documentation on nullable value types and they can easily be declared as eg `Vector3? position`

Comment: Why do you want to set `position`to null? Nulls are ambiguous and increase complexity. Why not implement the Null Object pattern and define a `Zero` or `Missing` instance ? Many types have `Empty` static fields (eg. String.Empty) that represent a type's single Null instance and make manipulations and handling of missing values a lot easier

Comment: Why are you setting `position`to null in the first place? You wouldn't need to do that unless you are reusing the variable outside the loop. A far better solution would be to change the code so the variable is *not* reused and there isn't any reason to clear it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) to do this:

```
Vector3? vector = null;
```

And assign its value from some place:

```
position = new Vector3();
```

And then you can easily compare it to `null` as you would have compared a reference type object:

```
if(position != null) //or position.HasValue if you want
{
    //...
}
```

After you verify it is not `null`, to access the `Vector3` value, you should use `position.Value`.

Comment: I think it's more idiomatic to check `position.HasValue`

Answer (score 5):

Can you declare it as a nullable Vector3 (Vector3?)?

```
Vector3? position = null;
```

That'd be my first suggestion. Alternatively, you could set it to Vector3.Zero, but I don't really like that idea.

I'm fairly certain Vector3 is a value type, not a reference type, so you can't assign null to it without explicitly declaring it as a nullable Vector3.

Comment: Either you want to assign null or `new Vector3()`. `Vector3?()` is a syntax error and frankly doesn't make any sense

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: As for `Vector3.Zero`, it's a **very good** idea and a common pattern (Null Object). Or `Vector3.Missing`. Null is ambiguous - it may mean not available, not valid, missing etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can have nullable value types using a the `Nullable<T>` where `T` is a `struct` (primite types) or adding a `?` after as a prefix of the type. With this you can set, for sample, a int, a [Vector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector(v=vs.110).aspx), or [Vector3d](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d(v=vs.110).aspx) structure as nullable, for sample:

```
Vector? vector2d = null;

Vector3d? vector3d = null;
```

When you have nullable types, you has two new properties, which is `HasValue` which returns a `bool` value indicating if there is a valid value for the object and `Value` which return the real value (for a `int?` return a `int`). You could use something like this:

```
// get a structure from a method which can return null
Vector3d? vector3d = GetVector();

// check if it has a value
if (vector3d.HasValue)
{
   // use Vector3d
   int x = vector3d.Value.X;
}
```

Actually, the `Nullable<T>` class tries to encapsulate the value types as a reference types to give the impression you can set null for a value type.

I think you know but I recommend you read more about [boxing and unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Use `Vector3?` (nullable Vector3) instead of `Vector3`.

Comment: So I have to use HasValue and Value each time now?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns what do you want to do with `null`anyway? You can use the `??`operator to extract the actual value or assign a default. You don't need to use `.Value`all the time

Comment: You can do something like `var copy = myVector ?? new Vector3(0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a value type to null.

Since Vector3 is a struct (which is a value type) you won't be able to set it to null as is.

You could use a nullable type like:

```
Vector3? position = null;
```

but that will require casting it to Vector3 when you want to use it in a function that is looking for regular Vector3.

Answer (score 0):

Vector3 is a struct and therefore is not nullable or disposable. You can either use

```cs
Vector3? position = null;
```

Or you can change it like this:

```cs
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Vector3 position = new Vector3())
        {
            //In some loop
           consumePositionAsForce(position);
        }
    }
}

struct Vector3 : IDisposable
{
    //Whatever you want to do here
}
```

The struct is now disposable so that you can use it in a using statement. This will kill the object after use. This is better than nulls since you don't over complicate things and you don't have to worry about missing a null check or event an undisposed object in memory.